# Getting a “segmentation Fault” on Caesar, Pset2

Tags: cs50, caesar-cipher

This is my code for Ceasar (pset2) of cs50.

I am able to compile my program.

However, on trying to execute it, I get a seg fault. Also, on using the debugger, I don't get a seg fault, but a ^D before the ciphertext is displayed. Much like this:

plaintext: HELLO
ciphertext: ^DIFMMP

Could you point out to me where the problem lies?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

bool is_numerical(string e);

int main(int argc, string argv [])
{
  if (argc == 2 && is_numerical(argv[1] == true))
   {
      string t = argv [1];
      int k = atoi ( t );
      string s = get_string ("plaintext: ");
      printf ("ciphertext:" );
      for (int i = 0, n = strlen(s); i < n; i++)
      {
         char c = s[i];
         if (isalpha (c))
         {
            if (isupper(c))
            {
               int x = ((int) c - 65 + k) % 26 + 65;
               printf ("%c", (char) x);
            }
            else
            {
               int x = ((int) c - 97 + k) % 26 + 97;
               printf ("%c", (char) x);
            }
         }
         else
         {
            printf ("%c", c);
         }
      }

      printf ("\n");
      return 0;
   }
   else
   {
       printf("Usage: ./caesar key \n");
       return 1;
   };
}

bool is_numerical(string e)
{
   for (int i = 0, n = strlen(e); i < n; i++)
   {
      if (!isalnum (e))
         return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: you probably meant that `return true` in your loop to be outside the loop. If you have that inside, it'll return as soon as it finds **one digit**, you probably want to check if the whole thing is only digits

Comment: Thank you so very much for your help. I have managed to overcome that hurdle. However, now that I have rectified it, it compiles, but I now get a seg fault... Could you help me with that? (I have edited the question accordingly...)

Comment: `is_numerical(argv[1] == true)`, shouldn't this be `is_numerical(argv[1]) == true` or more simply. just `is_numerical(argv[1])`. Please compile with `-Wall` to catch these kinds of mistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be quite a lot of things wrong with this.

First, let's acknowledge the elephant in the room-

```c
if (argc == 2 && is_numerical(argv[1] == true))
```

This checks if `argc` is equal to 2 **and** if `is_numerical` returns true when the argument is `argv[1] == true`, `argv[1]` *will be `true`* when `argc` is equal to 2. So really, you're passing an integer value to `is_numerical` everytime, a value of 1 - but it expects a value of `char*` or `string`.

You probably meant to do `is_numerical(argv[1]) == true`. i.e, pass `argv[1]` to `is_numerical` and compare the return value to `true`. You can also completely omit the true part since that's redundant in a boolean expression.

```c
if (argc == 2 && is_numerical(argv[1]))
```

Now, you have a fatal mistake in your `is_numerical` function.

```c
if (!isalnum(e))
```

`isalnum` takes a value of type `char` (actually `int`, but `char` will get promoted anyway). You're passing `e` to it. Guess what type is `e`, it's `string`, or `char*`. Shouldn't you be passing each character of the string, so `e[i]` inside that loop?

```c
if (!isalnum(e[i]))
```

There may be more algorithmic issues in your code that aren't immediately apparent. But the fatal mistake at `is_numerical` is the reason behind the segmentation fault.

Word of advice, **always** compile with `-Wall` to catch these mistakes during compilation.

Comment: Thank you so very much for your feedback. With your help, I have managed to resolve both the issues, and now it runs well. But there is only one box it doesn't tick off. The program handles non-numeric values too (like 1a). Any suggestions as to how I can correct that?

Comment: That sounds like a problem outside the context of this specific issue. If the answer helped you, consider [upvoting it instead of thanking](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269681/how-can-i-thank-this-website) and marking it as accepted by clicking the checkmark beside the answer. Please try to keep the topic of one question consistent.

Comment: I understand that. I have accepted your answer and even voted for it, although the latter hasn't been recorded.